# An explicit version of the Shimura correspondence for vector-valued modular forms or Jacobi forms

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms, weil-representation

In several papers one can find references to an isomorphism $$S_{k,\rho}^\text{new}\cong S_{2k-1}^{\text{new},\pm}(N)$$ between a space of half-integer weight $k$ vector-valued cusp forms with representation $\rho$ and a space of newforms of weight $2k-1$, given by the Shimura correspondence (see the references below, for example). It is a bit confusing to me how the Shimura correspondence should act on vector-valued objects, though I imagine one can work in the reverse direction using the Shintani lift. **The question is: Is there a reference where the map $S_{k,\rho}^\text{new}\xrightarrow{Shimura} S_{2k-1}^{\text{new},\pm}(N)$ is given explicitly for general levels $N$?**

Such an isomorphism would probably be constructed using Jacobi forms (these are isomorphic to spaces of vector-valued modular forms tranforming according to a Weil representation). One can find, for example in Skoruppa and Zagier's paper, a theorem of the following type:

There exists for any fundamental discriminant $\Delta$ and any $r$, $r^2\equiv \Delta\pmod{4m}$, a map $$S_{\Delta,r}:J_{k,m}\oplus J_{k,m}^*\to \text{a subspace of newforms}$$ and some linear combination of such maps is an isomorphism. So while the maps $S_{\Delta,r}$ are given explicitly, the isomorphism is not. In this paper the linear combination is only proven to exist, and could probably be computed for specific examples but is not given explicitly.

*Bruinier, Jan H.; Strömberg, Fredrik*, [**Computation of harmonic weak Maass forms**], (section 2.3) (https://doi.org/10.1080/10586458.2012.645778), Exp. Math. 21, No. 2, 117-131 (2012). [ZBL1304.11028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1304.11028).)

*Alfes, Claudia; Griffin, Michael; Ono, Ken; Rolen, Larry*, [**Weierstrass mock modular forms and elliptic curves**], (section 5) (https://doi.org/10.1007/s40993-015-0026-2), Res. Number Theory 1, Paper No. 24, 31 p. (2015). [ZBL1388.11019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1388.11019).

*Skoruppa, Nils-Peter; Zagier, Don*, [**Jacobi forms and a certain space of modular forms**] (theorem 5 and page 141) (https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01394347), Invent. Math. 94, No. 1, 113-146 (1988). [ZBL0651.10020](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0651.10020).